# Session hijack resulting in token exposure

Tags: php, session, token

I'm trying to wrap my head around session hijacking and the use of tokens for CSRF protecting.
I use this object method in each of my scripts to check whether a session variable is set or the token matches the session token.

```
public function admin_index(){

session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["user"]) || $_GET['token']!=$_SESSION['token']) {
    header("location: login/login_form.php");
    session_destroy();
    exit();
}
```

I'm new at this and my question is:
If my session id is somehow hijacked will he be able to some how also read my variable $_SESSION['token'] in the short time span after session_start and the the session data is fetched and populate in $_SESSION or is it still safe on the server?

Are session variables generally safe even though a valid session has been obtained?

Never mind the $_GET['token'] instead of POST. I'm still working on it.

Thanks

**EDIT:**

What I'm asking is. If a token also helps me secure my sessions the way I'm using it. If every query, link or view in my script requires a valid token and an attacker only got a hold of my session_id the tokens would be another layer of protection cause he/she would need both the id AND the token to do anything in the script, right?

And the token is secure on the server even though an attacker has acquired my session_id?

Comment: Just to reiterate, if your session has been hijacked, a csrf isn't of value.   Hope that is clear.  It does not help with session hijacking or prevention of the same.  What does often help is checking for a change of user agent and/or IP address, and of course the ultimate security is https: and secure cookies.

Comment: It will not help to protect your session as the CSRF token is generated each time the form is accessed. So, if I hijack your session and use your account to access that form then a new token is generated and I can do what I like regardless of what the CSRF token was before.

Comment: And in your example is is matching changes to the token or if the user is authenticated. You should only be using tokens for checking that data is coming from a trusted source. You seem to be using it as a secondary session id which isn't quite right. You could do this if you are creating a hash from unique identifiers of the user such as the session_id and the User-Agent of the browser as this could be checked every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Session Hijacking and CSRF attacks are two completely different things and once someone has your access to your session they are 'you' and can access everything on your account.

> A CSRF attack is an attack which forces an end user to execute
>   unwanted actions on a web application in which he/she is currently
>   authenticated

This is a social engineering and validation issue which using a token can obviously solve as it can be proved that the data was sent legitimately from your form. Using POST instead of GET will make this attack very difficult.

> A Session Hijack on the other hand is where someone can use your
>   session, become 'you' and use your account which will allow them to do
>   whatever they please.

Once a malicious user has access to this session a CSRF attack is pretty much useless as it is not needed.

If you are worried about your session ids being hijacked then you can take some precautionary measures such as regenerating a users session id once they are elevated to a higher level of access. This can be done using the session_regenerate_id() PHP function. You can also check the User Agent of the browser to check if there are changes and if there are then you can simply ask the user to login and regenerate the id so it is then unknown to the attacker. Obviously there is always a chance that they will be the same user agent but it does limit the risk significantly. Encryption such as SSL/HTTPS are also an option that you may want to look at

For more information you should check out this link for some examples: http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/4.html. Hopefully this has solved your problem :)

Comment: Hi Daniel, It deffinately helped me alot. I have looked into that document before. I read this other article which explains a token system like im trying to do. What do you think of it. Page 49-50: http://phpsecurity.org/ch04.pdf I guess it only work if a cookie is stolen therefore an attacker only has the session_id. If an attacker sniffs the http request he would have both the token and id. I did implement session regenrate as well. I just thought this would serve as an extra security.

Comment: Yeah I have implemented a similar session hijacking token in a past project that used something rather similar. This check can then be incorporated into your code that checks to see if a user is authenticated. The main cause of cookies to be stolen is XSS exploits so make sure you use htmlentities() on your output but also do sufficient validation and santisation checks and that should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm quite sure you simply can't hijack `$_SESSION` values because these, unlike `$_COOKIE` is saved on the server and not in the webbrowser.

Therefor they can't change it either. They can close their webbrowser to remove it, but not edit it.

Comment: Thanks Robin. That is what I'm hoping for too. So i'm guessing the only way to retrieve a session variable is if it's f.ex echoed back to the browser via a php script. And if such a script does not exist it's safe?

Comment: If I hijack your session, I AM you.  I am able to do whatever you do, and CSRF is irrelevant.  I'm already in your account.

Comment: But if you just acquired the session id from f.ex the http header, but  every query requires a token hidden in session_id. The token protects me from complete hijacking right? The attacker would need to have both the session id AND the token?

Comment: The session id ties you to the session.  The recommended way this association is maintained is a cookie.  If i intercept that cookie, that is how I can easily hijack your session.  People who go into a coffee house, and jump on wifi, then login to their favorite website on http, are the ones who are exposing themselves to a session hijack, not to mention anyone using wifi or any shared network with people that they can not trust not to sniff their packets.

Comment: ah, ok so if i'm on a sniffed network. My session_id AND the token (as a GET) would be visible in the request to the server not just the session_id? Would a ssl connection help this problem

Answer (score 0):

Session variables are stored on the server.  They can not be read. However, a session can be hijacked typically by an attacker getting access to the session id of another user, and can then use that session id to impersonate them (hijack) their session.

CSRF is an entirely different concern.  CSRF exploits get users to inadvertantly perform operations in a manner similar to xss exploits:  I might post a bogus img link where the src is actually a url that passes parameters to a script that your browser runs on your behalf.  In that case the attacker is simply getting your browser to make a request you didn't intend it to.  The CSRF protection should stop this, because the user does not know what the token is, so they can't embed it into the url.

Comment: Hi gview, thank you, but if an attacker gets hold of my session id, but every action in my script requires a token to execute. The token not only protects me from CSRF but also from hijacking, right? cause he would need both the session id and the token and the token is stored in the session.

Comment: No, because if your session is hijacked, the attacker is simply going to generate new forms which will disclose the token.  The token is a secret you generate on the server, and provide in a form or as a url parameter.   It only stops someone who does not have a session from tricking someone who does into performing get or post requests they didn't intend to.

Comment: hmm...but if run the above script on all my scripts you will not get to the forms if the token is missing. I append the token to all links not just the forms, so without the token nothing will work in the script even if you have the right session_id. You will be kicked out before getting to the forms. I got the idea from this pdf page 49-50: phpsecurity.org/ch04.pdf. Sorry to keep beating a dead horse ;-)